# How to display a div properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In this question, CSS is not important, it's a pure JavaScript problem.

I've tried to make it clear in the code itself, I've written how it should be working, but short version is that `#album` is visible by default, if you open any other `div`, it disappears. Basically only the currently opened `div` can be visible, if that's closed,`#albums` appears again, and it's working fine, expect for the `#toursdiv2`, which has a different way of working than the rest,it's not triggered the same way, and that's why I couldn't figure out a way to make it work like the rest.

Can I fix this without removing any part of my code?

```js
function showabout(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var tours=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 var albums=document.getElementById("albums");
 about.style.display=(about.style.display==="block"?"none":"block");
 if(about.style.display==="block"){
  albums.style.display="none";
  tours.style.display="none";
  awards.style.display="none";
 }
 
 else{
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 }
 // albums.style.display=(albums.style.display==="none"?"block":"none");
 
 
}
function showtours(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 about.style.display="none";
 var albums=document.getElementById("albums");
 var tours=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 tours.style.display=(tours.style.display==="block"?"none":"block");
 if(tours.style.display==="block" ){
  albums.style.display="none";
  awards.style.display="none";
  about.style.display="none";
  
 }
 
 else{
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 }
}
function showtours2(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 var tours1=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var tours2=document.getElementById("toursdiv2");
 tours1.style.display="none";
 tours2.style.display="block";
 if(tours2.style.display==="block"){
  about.style.display="none";
  awards.style.display="none";
  
 }

 else{
  
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 tours2.style.display="none";
 }
 
}
function showtours1(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 var tours1=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var tours2=document.getElementById("toursdiv2");
 tours2.style.display="none";
 tours1.style.display="block";
 
 // if(tours2.style.display==="block"){
  // about.style.display="none";
  // awards.style.display="none";
 // }
 // else{
 // albums.style.display="block";
 // albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn";
 // tours2.style.display=none;
 // }
}
function showawards(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 about.style.display="none";
 var albums=document.getElementById("albums");
 var tours=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 awards.style.display=(awards.style.display==="block"?"none":"block");
 if(awards.style.display==="block" ){
  albums.style.display="none";
  tours.style.display="none";
  about.style.display="none";
 }
 else{
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 }
}
```

```css
#menu{
 font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
 font-weight:bold;
 width:90%;
 height:10%;
 position:absolute;
 left:5%;
}
#menu a{
 color:#bba2a2;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#about,#tours,#channel,#website,#awards,#shop{
 
 height:80%;
 width:8%;
 font-size:20px;
}
#about{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:5%;
}
#tours{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:20%;
}
#channel{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:65%;
}
#website{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:50%;
}
#awards{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:35%;
}
#shop{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:80%;
}
#about span:hover,#tours span:hover,#channel span:hover,#website:hover,#awards span:hover,#shop:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
 border-radius:15px;
 color:red;
 transition:1s;
}
#website a:hover,#channel a:hover ,#shop a:hover{
 transition:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:red;
 transition:1s;
}

.about{
display:none;
}
#toursdiv,#toursdiv2{
display:none;
}
#awardsdiv{
display:none;
}
#toursnext{
 font-size:40px;
 position:absolute;
 top:25%;
 left:30%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#toursprevious{
 font-size:40px;
 position:absolute;
 top:25%;
 left:30%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<div id="menu">
<div id="about">
<span class="menus" onclick="showabout()">About</span>

</div>

<div id="tours">
<span class="menus" onclick="showtours()">Tours</span>

</div>

<div id="awards">
<span class="menus" onclick="showawards()">Awards</span>
</div>

</div>
<br><br><br><br>

<div id="albums">
This is <strong>ALBUMS</strong> div, this is visible by default, if any other div is visible, it disappears
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="about">
This is <strong>ABOUT</strong> div, becomes visible on click,if this is visible everything else isn't, and disappears if any other div becomes visible/by clicking on it again and then album div is visible
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="toursdiv">
This is the <strong>part 1 of TOURS</strong> div,becomes visible on click,if this is visible everything else isn't, and disappears if any other div becomes visible/by clicking on it again and then album div is visible
<i title="Click to show part 2" class="fa fa-arrow-right" id="toursnext" onclick="showtours2()"></i>

</div>
<br><br>
<div id="toursdiv2">
This is the <strong>part 2 of TOURS</strong> div, which I can't make to be working the same as the rest of the divs. If this is visible, and you open any other div, you'll see the problem, that I couldn't make it work like the rest of the div when opening new div
<i title="Click to show part 1" class="fa fa-arrow-left" id="toursprevious" onclick="showtours1()"></i>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="awardsdiv">
This is <strong>AWARDS</strong> div,becomes visible on click,if this is visible everything else isn't, and disappears if any other div becomes visible/by clicking on it again and then album div is visible
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it because you never change toursdiv2 to display none again everytime you choose other div. I update your code here ^^

```js
function showabout(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var tours=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var tours2=document.getElementById("toursdiv2");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 var albums=document.getElementById("albums");
 about.style.display=(about.style.display==="block"?"none":"block");
 if(about.style.display==="block"){
  albums.style.display="none";
  tours.style.display="none";
  tours2.style.display="none";
  awards.style.display="none";
 }
 
 else{
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 }
 // albums.style.display=(albums.style.display==="none"?"block":"none");
 
 
}
function showtours(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 about.style.display="none";
 var albums=document.getElementById("albums");
 var tours=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var tours2=document.getElementById("toursdiv2");
 tours.style.display=(tours.style.display==="block"?"none":"block");
 if(tours.style.display==="block" ){
  albums.style.display="none";
  awards.style.display="none";
  about.style.display="none";
  tours2.style.display="none";
  
 }
 
 else{
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 }
}
function showtours2(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 var tours1=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var tours2=document.getElementById("toursdiv2");
 tours1.style.display="none";
 tours2.style.display="block";
 if(tours2.style.display==="block"){
  about.style.display="none";
  awards.style.display="none";
  
 }

 else{
  
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 tours2.style.display="none";
 }
 
}
function showtours1(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 var tours1=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var tours2=document.getElementById("toursdiv2");
 tours2.style.display="none";
 tours1.style.display="block";
 
 // if(tours2.style.display==="block"){
  // about.style.display="none";
  // awards.style.display="none";
 // }
 // else{
 // albums.style.display="block";
 // albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn";
 // tours2.style.display=none;
 // }
}
function showawards(){
 var awards=document.getElementById("awardsdiv");
 var about=document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];
 about.style.display="none";
 var albums=document.getElementById("albums");
 var tours=document.getElementById("toursdiv");
 var tours2=document.getElementById("toursdiv2");
 awards.style.display=(awards.style.display==="block"?"none":"block");
 if(awards.style.display==="block" ){
  albums.style.display="none";
  tours.style.display="none";
  tours2.style.display="none";
  about.style.display="none";
 }
 else{
 albums.style.display="block";
 albums.style.WebkitAnimationName="slideIn"; //not important
 }
}
```

```css
#menu{
 font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
 font-weight:bold;
 width:90%;
 height:10%;
 position:absolute;
 left:5%;
}
#menu a{
 color:#bba2a2;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#about,#tours,#channel,#website,#awards,#shop{
 
 height:80%;
 width:8%;
 font-size:20px;
}
#about{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:5%;
}
#tours{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:20%;
}
#channel{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:65%;
}
#website{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:50%;
}
#awards{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:35%;
}
#shop{
 position:absolute;
 top:5%;
 left:80%;
}
#about span:hover,#tours span:hover,#channel span:hover,#website:hover,#awards span:hover,#shop:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
 border-radius:15px;
 color:red;
 transition:1s;
}
#website a:hover,#channel a:hover ,#shop a:hover{
 transition:1s;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:red;
 transition:1s;
}

.about{
display:none;
}
#toursdiv,#toursdiv2{
display:none;
}
#awardsdiv{
display:none;
}
#toursnext{
 font-size:40px;
 position:absolute;
 top:25%;
 left:30%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#toursprevious{
 font-size:40px;
 position:absolute;
 top:25%;
 left:30%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<div id="menu">
<div id="about">
<span class="menus" onclick="showabout()">About</span>

</div>

<div id="tours">
<span class="menus" onclick="showtours()">Tours</span>

</div>

<div id="awards">
<span class="menus" onclick="showawards()">Awards</span>
</div>

</div>
<br><br><br><br>

<div id="albums">
This is <strong>ALBUMS</strong> div, this is visible by default, if any other div is visible, it disappears
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="about">
This is <strong>ABOUT</strong> div, becomes visible on click,if this is visible everything else isn't, and disappears if any other div becomes visible/by clicking on it again and then album div is visible
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="toursdiv">
This is the <strong>part 1 of TOURS</strong> div,becomes visible on click,if this is visible everything else isn't, and disappears if any other div becomes visible/by clicking on it again and then album div is visible
<i title="Click to show part 2" class="fa fa-arrow-right" id="toursnext" onclick="showtours2()"></i>

</div>
<br><br>
<div id="toursdiv2">
This is the <strong>part 2 of TOURS</strong> div, which I can't make to be working the same as the rest of the divs. If this is visible, and you open any other div, you'll see the problem, that I couldn't make it work like the rest of the div when opening new div
<i title="Click to show part 1" class="fa fa-arrow-left" id="toursprevious" onclick="showtours1()"></i>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="awardsdiv">
This is <strong>AWARDS</strong> div,becomes visible on click,if this is visible everything else isn't, and disappears if any other div becomes visible/by clicking on it again and then album div is visible
</div>
```

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't figure it out, it's so simple. Thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept it as an answer too ^^